# Bloxorz a-Star Search

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, shortest-path, a-star

I am struggling to implement a-Star algorithm on [Bloxorz](https://www.miniclip.com/games/bloxorz/en/) game. Which the goal is reach the end using 1 x 1 x 2 block. I implement the algorithm but it is inconsistent. Sometimes it doesn't give the shortest solution. For example:

```
maze = ['00011111110000',
        '00011111110000',
        '11110000011100',
        '11100000001100',
        '11100000001100',
        '1S100111111111',
        '11100111111111',
        '000001E1001111',
        '00000111001111']
```

for this maze my implementation gives this result:

> U,L,U,R,R,U,R,R,R,R,R,R,D,R,D,D,D,L,L,L,D,R,D,L,U,R,U,L,D

which has 29 moves. But there is a shorter solution which has 28 moves:

> U,L,U,R,R,U,R,R,R,R,R,R,D,R,D,D,D,D,D,R,U,L,L,L,L,L,L,D

Here is my implementation, full code is [here](https://github.com/umitkara/Bloxorz/tree/master), what could i do for it?

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self,parent:'Node', node_type:str, x1:int, y1:int, x2:int, y2:int, direction:str=''):
        self.parent = parent
        self.node_type = node_type
        self.g = 0
        self.h = 0
        self.f = 0
        self.x1 = x1
        self.y1 = y1
        self.x2 = x2
        self.y2 = y2
        self.visited = False
        self.direction = direction
    def get_positions(self) -> tuple:
        return (self.x1, self.y1, self.x2, self.y2)
    def __eq__(self, other):
        if type(other) is Node:
            return self.x1 == other.x1 and self.y1 == other.y1 and self.x2 == other.x2 and self.y2 == other.y2
        elif type(other) is tuple:
            return self.x1 == other[0] and self.y1 == other[1] and self.x2 == other[2] and self.y2 == other[3]
        else:
            return False
    def __lt__(self, other:'Node'):
        return self.f < other.f

def aStar(start:Node, end:Node, grid:List[List[str]]) -> List[tuple]:
    open_list = []
    closed_list = []
    heapq.heappush(open_list, start)
    while open_list:
        current:Node = heapq.heappop(open_list)
        if current == end:
            return reconstruct_path(current)
        closed_list.append(current)
        for neighbor in get_neighbors(current, grid):
            if neighbor not in closed_list:
                neighbor.g = current.g + 1
                neighbor.h = get_heuristic(neighbor, end)
                neighbor.f = neighbor.g + neighbor.h
                if neighbor not in open_list:
                    heapq.heappush(open_list, neighbor)
    return []

def reconstruct_path(current:Node) -> List[tuple]:
    path = []
    while current.parent is not None:
        path.append(current.direction)
        current = current.parent
    return ''.join(path[::-1])

def get_heuristic(current:Node, end:Node) -> int:
    return max(abs(current.x2 - end.x1), abs(current.y2 - end.y1))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming everything else in your implementation is correct, it's just because your heuristic is not admissible.

Consider the maze:

```
B 1 1 X
```

You can reach the goal in 2 moves:

```
1 B B X : move1
1 1 1 B : move2
```

But your heuristic suggests that it would take at least 3 moves

```
max(abs(current.x2 - end.x1), abs(current.y2 - end.y1))
= max(abs(0-3), abs(0-0)) = max(3, 0) = 3
```

The heuristic function can't over-estimate the number of moves it would take to reach the goal for A* to always give optimal paths, because doing so might leave a potential optimal path un-explored upon reaching the goal (the optimal path may have never been expanded because it's cost was over-estimated by h(n)).

You would want a heuristic which takes into account the fact that a given coordinate can change by up to 2 in any given move (when a block goes from standing to lying or vice versa). For this, you could divide the result of your current heuristic function by 2.

```
def get_heuristic(current:Node, end:Node) -> int:
    return 1/2 * max(abs(current.x2 - end.x1), abs(current.y2 - end.y1))
```

This gives the length 28 path `ULURRURRRRRRDRDDDDDRULLLLLLD`.

Comment: Thanks for your response. With your help i did it. I put how on the answer. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

As inordirection said the problem is about the heuristic function. inordirection's answer not work directly but gave me some idea and i came up with this that works.

```
return 1/4 * max(max(abs(current.x1 - end.x1), abs(current.y1 - end.y1)), max(abs(current.x2 - end.x2), abs(current.y2 - end.y2)))
```

Because there might be two points locating the block i should have choose maximum difference of x1 and x2 from end, and y1 and y2 from end than choose maximum of them and multiply by 1/4 because it's chosen from 4 points.

Comment: Ah, I thought about including all 4 points but I didn't think it was necessary. Maybe I just couldn't think of the right counter-example. But are you sure you need to multiply by 1/4th? The fact that there are 2 or 4 possible points to consider has no direct relationship with the multiplier- it's just about giving an estimate of the minimum number of moves it might take to reach the goal (and I used 1/2 because a move can get you 2 steps closer).

Comment: In general, you want to make your heuristic value as big as possible without over-estimating, because the larger it is the more effectively you can prune the search space, so A* can run faster. If you have a zero heuristic, for example, A* devolves into BFS.

Comment: I tested 1/2 over 150 cases it passed 145. Because of that i came up with this. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Here is one example that fails:
['01100000000000000000',
'11110000011001111111',
'11111111111001111111',
'1B111111111001110011',
'11110000011111110011',
'11110000011111110011',
'00000000000000000011',
'11111111101110011011',
'11X11011101111111111',
'11110011111110011000']

The soultion has 40 steps. Shortest has 39. With 1/4 this could be avoided.

Comment: Strange. I got it to work with this:

`def get_heuristic(current:Node, end:Node) -> int:
    maxXdist = max(abs(current.x1 - end.x1), abs(current.x2 - end.x1))
    maxYdist = max(abs(current.y1 - end.y1), abs(current.y2 - end.y1))
    return 0.4999 * max(maxXdist, maxYdist)`

but not with `0.5`. Must be overlooking something. Anyway, thank you.